# Redmine installation, show error 500 when I try to load a user add

Tags: centos7, redmine

I'm trying to change admin user settings, but it does not load the screen, even though it's a new installation, so I do not know what happens. The installation is in an operating system of centos 7 and is the last version of redmine 3.4.2

link: 
http://redmine.devitech.com.co/users/1/edit
Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Back

I would greatly appreciate yours helps

Comment: You are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Comment: I do not know where redmine saves the execution log, try in the [redmine_home] / log post but the files that come out are delete.me development.log production.log and seeing them does not display information about it

Comment: Make sure that Redmine (that is: probably the user running your app server processes) can write to these files. Usually, Redmine should write logs about each request to the `production.log` file. Without any logs, there is no way we can help you at all.